# Put JSON array data in Hashmap and pass it through Intent Extra

Tags: java, android, json, android-intent, arrays

In my app, I have successfully implemented passing JSON Objects via Intent to a  new activity by doing find "findviewByid."

Now this is a restaurant finder app, and each restaurant has several menu photos. I was looking all over stackoverflow to find sth like it but couldn't implement.

This is a part of my JSON file:

```
[
{
login_id: "6",

name: "Urban Spice",

location: "banani",

latitude: "23.790327",

longitude: "90.409007",

address: "House- 119, Road-11, Block-E, Banani",
rating: "4.00",

costfortwopeople: "0",

openingclosingtime: "",

type: "restaurant,ice cream parlour",

perks: "kids zone,home delivery,catering",

cuisine: "indian,indonesian",

phone: "01777899901,2,3,9862672",

image: - [

"http://www.petuuk.com/restaurant_images/img_2146.jpg",

"http://www.petuuk.com/restaurant_images/img_2147.jpg"
],

menu: - [

"http://www.petuuk.com/restaurant_images/.jpg",
"http://www.petuuk.com/restaurant_images/.jpg",
"http://www.petuuk.com/restaurant_images/.jpg",
"http://www.petuuk.com/restaurant_images/.jpg",
"http://www.petuuk.com/restaurant_images/.jpg",
"http://www.petuuk.com/restaurant_images/.jpg",
"http://www.petuuk.com/restaurant_images/.jpg",
"http://www.petuuk.com/restaurant_images/.jpg"
]
},

 {

login_id: "7",

name: "The Sky Room Dining",

location: "banani",

latitude: "23.793972",

longitude: "90.403190",

address: "ABC House, 12th Floor, 8 Kemal Ataturk Avenue, Banani",

rating: "4.00",

costfortwopeople: "0",

openingclosingtime: "",

type: "restaurant",

perks: "rooftop view,catering",

cuisine: "thai,indian",

phone: "01675019211,9822017",

image: - [
"http://www.petuuk.com/restaurant_images/img_2204.jpg",
"http://www.petuuk.com/restaurant_images/img_2205.jpg",
"http://www.petuuk.com/restaurant_images/img_2206.jpg"
],  etc..................................................................
```

I'm having a hard time retrieving the JSON array "menu" and "image" from the JSON output as above. I was able to retrieve the other JSON Objects such as login_id, name, location etc.

The main objective I am trying to achieve here is, load all the data in the Listview, where a user can search a restaurant, then when the user clicks on the specific restaurant, all the loaded data should gets into the "Intent.putExtra" for getting viewed in a full restaurant profile view in a new activity.

These are parts of my "SeachAll" activity where I need help. This is the for loop for retrieving data from the JSON file. I need help here retrieving data from "image" and "menu" and then putting it into my hashmap.

```
 protected String doInBackground(String... arg) {
        //building parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

        //Getting JSON from URL
        String json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(URL_RESTAURANT_LIST, "GET", params);

        //Log Cat Response Check
        Log.d("Areas JSON: ", "> " + json);

        try {
            restaurants = new JSONArray(json);

            if (restaurants != null) {
                //loop through all restaurants
                for (int i = 0; i < restaurants.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = restaurants.getJSONObject(i);

                    //Storing each json  object in the variable.
                    String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
                    String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                    String location = c.getString(TAG_LOCATION);
                    String rating = c.getString(TAG_RATING);`  HashMap<String, String>  map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    //adding each child node to Hashmap key
                    map.put(TAG_ID, id);
                    map.put(TAG_NAME, name);
                    map.put(TAG_LOCATION, location);
                    map.put(TAG_RATING, rating);


                    //adding HashList to ArrayList
                    restaurant_list.add(map);
                }

            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }`
```

This is my onItemClick. Need help in putting the arrays, I dont know if it is alright to pass json array just like json objects i did below.

```
ListView lv = getListView();
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), RestaurantProfile.class);
            String loginId = ((TextView) view.
                    findViewById(R.id.login_id)).
                    getText().toString();

            String res_name = ((TextView) view.
                    findViewById(R.id.restaurant_name)).
                    getText().toString();


            intent.putExtra(TAG_ID, loginId);
            intent.putExtra(TAG_NAME, res_name);

            startActivity(intent);


        }
    });
```

So In brief I need help with two things,

**1. Retrieve JSON array "image" and "menu" URLS from the JSON file and put it inside the Hashmap.**

**2. Put this data to my Intent for being passed to a new activity.**

This my full code for "SearchAll" activity.

```
public class SearchAll extends ListActivity {

ConnectionDetector cd;
AlertDialogManager alert = new AlertDialogManager();

//Progress Dialog
private ProgressDialog pDialog;

//make json parser Object
JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> restaurant_list;

//Restaurant Json array
JSONArray restaurants = null;

private static final String URL_RESTAURANT_LIST 
  = "http://www.petuuk.com/android/allRestaurantList2.php";

//all JSON Node Names
private static final String TAG_ID = "login_id";
private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";
private static final String TAG_LOCATION = "location";
private static final String TAG_LAT = "lattitude";
private static final String TAG_LONG = "longitude";
private static final String TAG_ADDRESS = "address";
private static final String TAG_COST_2 = "costfortwopeople";
private static final String TAG_TYPE = "type";
private static final String TAG_PERKS = "perks";
private static final String TAG_CUISINE = "cuisne";
private static final String TAG_PHONE = "phone";
private static final String TAG_RATING = "rating";
private static final String TAG_IMAGE = "image";
private static final String TAG_MENU = "menu";
private static final String TAG_TIMING = "openingclosingtime";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_search_all);

    cd = new ConnectionDetector(getApplicationContext());

    //Check for Internet Connection
    if (!cd.isConnectingToInternet()) {
        //Internet connection not present
        alert.showAlertDialog(SearchAll.this, "Internet Connection Error",
                "Please Check Your Internet Connection", false);
        //stop executing code by return
        return;
    }

    restaurant_list = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();



    //get ListView
    ListView lv = getListView();
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
   public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

      Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), RestaurantProfile.class);
            String loginId = ((TextView) view.
                    findViewById(R.id.login_id)).
                    getText().toString();

            String res_name = ((TextView) view.
                    findViewById(R.id.restaurant_name)).
                    getText().toString();


            intent.putExtra(TAG_ID, loginId);
            intent.putExtra(TAG_NAME, res_name);

            startActivity(intent);


        }
    });

    lv.setOnScrollListener(new EndlessScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLoadMore(int page, int totalItemsCount) {

        }
    });

    new LoadRestaurants().execute();



}


class LoadRestaurants extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    //Show Progress Dialog
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(SearchAll.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading All Restaurants...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    protected String doInBackground(String... arg) {
        //building parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

        //Getting JSON from URL
        String json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(URL_RESTAURANT_LIST, "GET", params);

        //Log Cat Response Check
        Log.d("Areas JSON: ", "> " + json);

        try {
            restaurants = new JSONArray(json);

            if (restaurants != null) {
                //loop through all restaurants
                for (int i = 0; i < restaurants.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = restaurants.getJSONObject(i);

                    //Storing each json  object in the variable.
                    String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
                    String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                    String location = c.getString(TAG_LOCATION);
                    String rating = c.getString(TAG_RATING);
                    String address = c.getString(TAG_ADDRESS);
                    String latitude = c.getString(TAG_LAT);
                    String longitude = c.getString(TAG_LONG);
                    String costfor2 = c.getString(TAG_COST_2);
                    String timing = c.getString(TAG_TIMING);
                    String type = c.getString(TAG_TYPE);
                    String perks = c.getString(TAG_PERKS);
                    String cuisine = c.getString(TAG_CUISINE);
                    String phone = c.getString(TAG_PHONE);


                    JSONArray menuArray = c.getJSONArray("menu");
                    JSONArray imagesArray = c.getJSONArray("image");


                    //Creating New Hashmap
                    HashMap<String, String>  map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    //adding each child node to Hashmap key
                    map.put(TAG_ID, id);
                    map.put(TAG_NAME, name);
                    map.put(TAG_LOCATION, location);
                    map.put(TAG_RATING, rating);
                    for(int m=0;m<menuArray.length();++m){
                        map.put("MENU_" + m,menuArray.getString(m));
                    }//menu for loop
                    map.put("TOTAL_MENU", menuArray.length());


              //      map.put(TAG_MENU, String.valueOf(menu));

                    //adding HashList to ArrayList
                    restaurant_list.add(map);
                }

            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {

        //dismiss the dialog
        pDialog.dismiss();


        //Updating UI from the Background Thread
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                        SearchAll.this, restaurant_list,
                        R.layout.listview_restaurants, new String[]{
                        TAG_ID, TAG_NAME, TAG_LOCATION, TAG_RATING}, new int[]{
                  R.id.login_id, R.id.restaurant_name, R.id.location,  R.id.rating});

                setListAdapter(adapter);


            }
        });


    }
}
```

}

Comment: So where are you having hard time? While parsing or while passing?

Comment: Dont know what code to put in to parse in the "doInBackground" method and then put that in hashmap and after that in the Intent extra.

Answer (score 0):

**not sure of this is exactly what you need, but you might get some ideas out of this**

first, to get the image and menu array, from the restaurant, you need this

inside the for loop, where you get the json object (c)

```
JSONObject c = restaurants.getJSONObject(i);
JsonArray menuArray = c.getJsonArray("menu");
JsonArray imagesArray = c.getJsonArray("image");
```

and you can loop among menuArray and imagesArray items using a for loop

```
imagesArray.getString(index);
```

now, as you have declared your map as `< String, String >` you can't assign a multiple values (images or menu items) in one string,

so either you find another way to structure your data,
or create another 2 maps, menuPam, imageMap that will have restaurant ID as key, and String as value for menu and image entries.

inside the for loop that read restaurant objects:

```
for (int i = 0; i < restaurants.length(); i++) {
    :
    :
    map.put(TAG_ID, id);
    map.put(TAG_NAME, name);
    :
    :

    JsonArray menuArray = c.getJsonArray("menu");
    for(int m=0;m<menuArray.length();++m){
        menuMap.add(id,menuArray.getString(m));
    }//menu for loop

    //another for loop for imageArray...
}//end of restaurants loop
```

but then you have to add the menuMap and imageMap to an array list, called menus, images...

why don't you create an object to hold all info about restaurant

```
class restaurant{
private String name="", id =""....
//setters and getters ...

String menuItems[] = null;
String imageItems[] = null;

//setters getters for the arrays.
}
```

}

**EDIT:**
this sol does not need a new maps, just add images and menu to same map
using dynamic key name

```
for(int m=0;m<menuArray.length();++m){
    map.add("MENU_" + m,menuArray.getString(m));
}//menu for loop
map.add("TOTAL_MENU", Integer.toString(menuArray.length()));
```

you can use above code, to add menu items to the map 
and same thing to images, "IMAGE_"+m
and TOTAL_IMAGES

now at target activity, read all IMAGE_n and MENU_n in a loop
from 0 to TOTAL_IMAGES, and TOTAL_MENU

Comment: So i did what you told me. Can u please edit the codes that are not needed. I initaited the JSONArray as u said in the top and then in the map I used ur code as instructed in the edit. But Im getting an error in last line the "map.add("TOTAL_MENU", menuArray.length());". It says put (String, java.lang.String) in hashmap cannot be applied to (String, int). I posted my full searchall activity code. Please check it out and help.

Comment: yes, this because of adding Int in String param, replace menuArray.length() with this Integer.toString(menuArray.length())

Answer (score 0):

In short, you don't pass all of your data from one Activity to another. You should just pass a restaurant ID to a new Activity, and it uses that ID to pull data of the restaurant.

You should consider your restaurant list as (part of) Model in an MVC architecture. It should be separated from your Activities (which are Controller). Model is your data expert, it keeps your data in memory, files or a database, and it lives beyound the life-cycle of any particular Activity. You don't pass the Model from one Activity to another. After an Activity is created, it grabs the Model (if the Model is a Singleton) or the Model is injected into that Activity (Dependency Injection, my prefer framework is Dagger). The Activity then can ask for any particular data from the Model and render its View. It can also observe for any further changes within the Model and update its view accordlingly.

Comment: But will not even that cost a lot of time to load the restaurant? Because there is a lot of restaurant ids and it has to search them?

Comment: Also by your suggestion if you could point to some tutorials that would really help.

Comment: Store your restaurants inside a `Map` with key is restaurant ID and value is `Restaurant` object. Using an ID to get a `Restaurant` out of the `Map` is fast.

Comment: Google can give you lots of MVC tutorials :) If you prefer to read code, this may be helpful: https://github.com/github/android/blob/9d490829b944d3a2c77dbd0010ec7a0bfe2efaee/app/src/main/java/com/github/mobile/ui/gist/GistsFragment.java#L63